# Problem accessing MySql database on xampp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

So, i'm using Xampp 1.7.3 on my windows machine to run a server, never had any issues until now.
Somehow, i just "lost" connection with my database. The server can communicate without any problems, but when i try to access by typing "127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin or localhost/phpmyadmin" i just get a page saying that the Site can't be reached.
Already tried to restart the services and the machine itself, nothing worked.
Haven't tried to reinstall xampp simply because i can't kill the server. I need something to fix that WITHOUT reinstalling xampp

Comment: Is your webserver working?  (Does it show the index.html page in your DocumentRoot?)

Comment: Additionally to what Luuk has asked, check the XAMPP control panel to see if Apache is running correctly.